# Notifications for orders from customer to employee flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, notifications, flutter-notification

How do I make notifications for orders?
I have an application that contains a customer and an employee, and when the customer requests a request, a notification must be sent to the employee, how can I do that
Knowing that I have a card containing the order data, and when the customer clicks, I need to send a notification to the employee with this card that contains the order

Comment: use fcm to push notification

Answer (score 0):

you need push notifications provider, i recommend Firebase cloud messaging.

check this links

[firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/client)

[freecodecamp blog](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-push-notifications-to-flutter-app/amp/)

Comment: How can I get tokens?

Comment: what do you mean token? Describe what you want in detail